# multipage form error in javascript

Tags: javascript

hello guys I'm trying to make a Multipage form in java script but keep receiving the error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null; I've searched and found answers but to no avail.... it seems to work fine until I implement the show element function later in the code.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write('page'+1)

function hideElement(element)
{
 document.getElementById(element).style.display = 'none';
}
function showElement(element)
{
 document.getElementById(element).style.display = 'initial';
}


/*function lastPage()
{ 
  hideElement('page'+i-1);
  showElement('page'+i);
}
*/






</script>
```

Comment: It means that `document.getElementById(element)` is returning `null`. That happens when there's no actual element in the DOM matching the given id.

Comment: Also, "initial" is not a valid value for the CSS "display" property.

Comment: @Pointy [initial](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-values/#common-keywords) is a valid value for every CSS property.

Comment: @Quentin yes I just checked; you're right. I haven't used that in many many years I think :)

Comment: @Quentin ... maybe it's because it's never worked in IE.

Comment: thank you so much for the help , do you know why they would  return null if I have the ids page1,page2,page3, and page4 later in my html ? @Quentin